# Extracting HTML table cell text from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract "Canada", which is based on the text "Place of Birth". How can this be done with `beautifulsoup`?

```
<html>
    <table class="table1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Date(s) of Birth Used</td>
                <td>May 14, 1942</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Place of Birth</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: `<td>Place of Birth</td>` this is stable `td` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this for **dynamic td value**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = '''<html>
                <table class="table1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Date(s) of Birth Used</td>
                            <td>May 14, 1942</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Place of Birth</td>
                            <td>Canada</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
table_div = soup.find(class_ = "table1")
td_val = table_div.findAll('td')
updated_td_val = list(map(str, td_val))

# You can use input() instead of '<td>Place of Birth</td>' to take dynamic input and on basis of that input, it will return you the content of input td and it's next td.

if updated_td_val and '<td>Place of Birth</td>' in updated_td_val:
    index_val = updated_td_val.index('<td>Place of Birth</td>')
    print(td_val[index_val].get_text())
    print(td_val[index_val+1].get_text())
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Place of Birth
Canada
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is easier to read using bs4 4.7.1+ syntax and use :contains to match on td node with target text then [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to get next td

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
    <table class="table1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Date(s) of Birth Used</td>
                <td>May 14, 1942</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Place of Birth</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('td:contains("Place of Birth") + td').text)
```